# Call XSJS Service from SAPUI5 Application in webide

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to make an ajax call to **XSJS** service. With the new webide, we need to use the destination to make a call to the desired service. I have already setup a destination for my HANA System and exposed an XSJS service. What's the process to call the service from my controller file (in SAPUI5 App)?

Note: I have added the destination created in cockpit to my `neo-app.json` file as below:

```
 {
        "path": "/TestDest",
        "target": {
            "type": "destination",
            "name": "TestDest"
        },
        "description": "Test Destination"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [JQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) as it is stated [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/68/63e48a71aa48479ab4183892e7e4d8/content.htm)

Comment: Apologise if the question is not clear Shidai. I know I have to make an ajax call. But I cannot make calls to an absolute URL. I need to use the destination set in cockpit for making outbound calls. I wanted to know how is that done in an SAPUI5 Application developed in webide

Answer (score -1):

Check this link : https://blogs.sap.com/2016/04/13/sapui5-application-consuming-odata-service-with-sap-web-ide/

or configure the service url in component.js or manifest.json

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)